# Convert a sensor raw string to json using Python

Tags: python, json

Hello i have output data from sensor and im using a python script to send those data using post method but first i need to converts them to json but can't figure it out.

ex. string is

```
H2 14199        Ethanol 18151
```

and i want to convert it to

```
{
    "H2" : "14199",
    "Ethanol" : "18151"
}
```

so i can POST it in json format.

I tried some code on python but im not that much familiar to it.

Comment: What kind of code have you already tried? Could you please post it in the question body? What seems to be the problem with the approach you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
>>> s = 'H2 14199        Ethanol 18151'
>>> result = dict(map(str.split, s.split('        ')))
>>> result
{'H2': '14199', 'Ethanol': '18151'}
```

Use the `json` module to convert the `dict` to a JSON string:

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(result)
'{"H2": "14199", "Ethanol": "18151"}'
```